# Circular Dependency; how to remove Cart has CartItems and CartItems needs to know which Cart has it

Tags: php, dependencies

I have an application where a `Cart` model has an array of `CartItems`. But sometimes the `CartItem` needs to know properties about the cart such as what the price_tier of the cart is or the `sale id` of the cart to make calculations about the items in the cart such as price.

Is this an ok reason to have a circular dependency? How would I factor this out? It seems odd to have an item have properties such as tier_id and sale_id just to avoid a circular dependancy.

Comment: why calculations about the items in the cart such as price occurs in `CartItem`?

Comment: Overall options of the cart can cause price calculations for items be be different. For example the "Loyal customer" price tier could be set. Items can define what their price is for loyal customer tier. So the cart item would need to know if the state of the cart has a tier.

Comment: i think this is not problem when child has link to parent if it necessary